# How to I dynamically add a pytest marker with my own pytest classes?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to add some manual markers to the discovered tests I am doing at [https://github.com/pycontribs/pytest-molecule/blob/master/pytest_molecule/**init**.py#L53](https://github.com/pycontribs/pytest-molecule/blob/master/pytest_molecule/__init__.py#L53)

Mainly I want to conditionally add the "foo" mark so some of the discovered tests but I was not able to find any documentation on how to do it with classes based on `pytest.Item` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermid, I found:

```
    self.add_marker('foo')
```

This works because Item inherits Node which has this method.